# scanf keeps running nonstop

Tags: c, scanf

I have been trying to run the scanf() on my mac, but it never worked (took forever to run the program). Everything else like the printf works fine!

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    char name[20];
    printf("What is your name? \n");
    scanf("%19s", name);
    return 0;
}
```

terminal

```
[Running] cd "/Users/yiminghuang/Documents/C/" && gcc scanf4.c -o scanf4 && "/Users/yiminghuang/Documents/C/"scanf4

[Done] exited with code=null in 8.611 seconds

[Running] cd "/Users/yiminghuang/Documents/C/" && gcc scanf4.c -o scanf4 && "/Users/yiminghuang/Documents/C/"scanf4

[Done] exited with code=null in 10.384 seconds

[Running] cd "/Users/yiminghuang/Documents/C/" && gcc scanf3.c -o scanf3 && "/Users/yiminghuang/Documents/C/"scanf3

[Done] exited with code=null in 15.999 seconds
```

Comment: Your code looks fine although it doesn't do much. Add some printfs (like `printf("Your name is: %s\n", name);` right before `return 0;` and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to C programming, so please excuse me if I fail to answer your question correctly!

Now, the program you wrote works perfectly fine but as soon as you enter a string separated by a `space`, it only takes the characters before the `space`.

To solve this problem, you can use `fgets()` function of C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 100

int main(){

    char name[MAX];
    printf("What is your name? \n");
    fgets(name, MAX, stdin);
    printf("String = %s", name);
    return 0;
}
//i have used fgets() here for getting the input
//it is a better option than gets()
//since it bounds your array and prevents buffer overflow
```

I have also added a `printf()` to check if the string is stored correctly.

**IMPORTANT:** `fgets()` also consider the newline character i.e. `'\n'` as a part of your string. So better to keep that in mind.

[Check this question to know more about `fgets()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70798150/13781451)

Regards!

Comment: Please to not advise to use the unsafe and deprecated `gets`! Use `fgets` to read a full line (beware it keeps the newline in the string...)

Comment: @SergeBallesta If the answer seems correct now, can you please upvote it?

Comment: I was not the downvoter. But I agree that this answer no longer deserves a -1...

Comment: @SergeBallesta Thanks a lot! Really appreciate your help. :-)