# Why does this C program to calculate string's length give a wrong output?

Tags: c, newline, fgets, string-length, strlen

I have written this program which accepts a `string` as an input and return the length of it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX 100

int main()
{
    char a[MAX];
    int len;
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    fgets(a, MAX, stdin);

    len = strlen(a);
    printf("Length of the string = %d", len);

    return 0;
}
```

Since the function `strlen()` doesn't count null character i.e. `'\0'`, why is my output always 1 more than the characters of input `string`?

For Example -

```
Enter a string: Aryan
Length of the string = 6
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time: 4.372 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Comment: It is including the newline at the end of the input line.

Comment: So, do I have to manually subtract 1 from the len variable? I really don't know. Sorry

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The function `fgets` can append to the entered string the new line character `'\n'` if there is a space in the supplied array.

From the C Standard (7.21.7.2 The fgets function)

> 2 The fgets function reads at most one less than the number of
> characters specified by n from the stream pointed to by stream into
> the array pointed to by s. N**o additional characters are read after a
> new-line character (which is retained)** or after end-of-file. A null
> character is written immediately after the last character read into
> the array

Thus in this call of `strlen`

```
len = strlen(a);
```

the new line character is also counted.

You need to remove it as for example

```
a[ strcspn( a, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
```

or

```
char *p = strchr( a, '\n' );
if ( p != NULL ) *p = '\0';
```

Comment: Oh so it is happening because there is extra space in the given array! Let me try this...
Edit: This worked like charm! Can you suggest a simpler approach, if that's okay with you?

Comment: `a[ strcspn( a, "\n" ) ] = '\0';`  is the simplest approach of getting rid of the `\n`.

Answer (score 4):

The `fgets()` call includes the newline read from the input stream. This is useful, because it allows you to check if the line was read completely. If the input did not have a newline as last character, then the line read was incomplete.

```
int main()
{
    char a[MAX];
    size_t len;   // being precise with your types is a good habit
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    fgets(a, MAX, stdin);

    len = strlen(a);

    if ( a[len - 1] == '\n' )
    {
        // Usually you don't want the newline in there.
        a[--len] = '\0';
        // --len above corrected the length.
        printf("Length of the string = %zu\n", len);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Length of the string longer than %d\n", MAX - 1);
        // You can repeat fgets() until you get the whole line,
        // or keep reading (and throwing away) from input until
        // you get a newline. It really depends on how you want
        // to handle the error.
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but honestly, there are some things which I didn't understand. Your code works absolutely fine but since I am new to C, it will take time to digest this! Still, kudos to you buddy!

Comment: @AryanSoni Just ask, I am happy to help.

Comment: I wanted to know  what this `if else` statement does. Like, the use of `--len` is new for me. And also `size_t`.

Comment: @AryanSoni: `size_t` is the actual return value of `strlen()`; a typedef (a kind of alias) for an unsigned integer. (Because string lengths cannot be negative.) Once I have determined `len`, I check if the character at position `[ len - 1 ]` is a newline. The expression `a[ --len ] = '\0'` could be also written as `len = len - 1; a[ len ] = '\0';` i.e. reducing `len` by one and replacing the newline with a null byte -- shortening the string by that one character.

Comment: Explained very amazingly! Thanks a lot, man.

Comment: @AryanSoni: My pleasure. Have fun!